# Rise up (PPT) animation in CSS

Tags: css, powerpoint, css-animations

In PPT Presentation, there is an option of **Rise up**. In that option, the object first moves up, slows down, and comes back and then stops finally. Link to the animation effect: 
[image]

How can we make it in CSS?

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: jump 1s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: jump 1s ease-out;
  animation: jump 1s ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i268.photobucket.com/albums/jj6/SK_CRISIS/Emblem%20BG%20PNGs/Circle.png">
```

My version works but doesn't jump backwards as the PPT animation does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `animation-timing-function` from `ease-out` to `cubic-bezier()`

The point is, if you want the ball to return by giving a simple `translate` animation, The **y-axis** of both the handles **must** be greater than one.

`cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2)` <-- Here, `y1` and `y2` should be > 1.

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: jump 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.2, 0.8, 1.2);
  animation: jump 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.2, 0.8, 1.2);
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i268.photobucket.com/albums/jj6/SK_CRISIS/Emblem%20BG%20PNGs/Circle.png">
```

Comment: `transition-timing-function` ----> `animation-timing-function`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cubic-bezier(0.02, 1.24, 1, 1.18)` instead of `ease-out`.

Change the co-ordinate values as per your needs.

Also, the `-moz-` prefix is not necessary, `@keyframes` are [fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes) on Firefox.

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  -webkit-animation: jump 1s cubic-bezier(0.02, 1.24, 1, 1.18);
  animation: jump 1s cubic-bezier(0.02, 1.24, 1, 1.18);
}
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i268.photobucket.com/albums/jj6/SK_CRISIS/Emblem%20BG%20PNGs/Circle.png">
```